# App is shipped with old persisted data even after release build

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-persist

I am using `redux persist` and I have previously persisted a list of data, but even after building the app in release, the app is shipped with some previous data that's not cleared out. A fresh build is not there , I have tried the following

```
react-native run-android --variant=release
```

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

I have also run this code to bundle, but no use

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

This is causing an error for me on initial app start up cuz of the old data, and the only way I am able to clear data is clearing app data from device `settings`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems the issue was from backup process being enabled , this helped https://stackoverflow.com/a/55294158/7266219